# A married woman who slept with different men countless times

Tags: sin

A woman who got married slept with different men on countless times but after every sex she regrets but still commits the same thing.She wants to repent but does not know if Allah will forgive her, it is a major sin and the adulterers will not smell the fragrance of Jannah.

1)Will Allah ever forgive her?

2)How can she ask for forgiveness from Allah?

3)Should she ask her husband for forgiveness before asking Allah?

Comment: Allah has promised to forgive our sins even if they were as large as mountain if we do sincere repentance and don't die on shirk. So believe in Your Creator & ask forgiveness from Him like you truly mean it. Your heart will show you the way, tears will flow & your skin will get goosebumps. You just need to be sincere.

Comment: #3 is an issue of dispute among the scholars & it is best to reach out to your local aalim/aalima to deal with it on a case to case basis.